# plot nothing but the legend in matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a bunch of subplots and one I want to contain a legend (there are the same number of handles and labels in each of the other subplots so I just want a master legend for all of them).

```
|plot|gap1|plot|
|plot|plot|plot|
|plot|gap2|plot|
```

Now where the gap1, I want to put my master legend. I plotted the same in the first subplot.

```
line1 = ax2.plot(x1,y2,'--',color='b',linewidth=2)
line2 = ax2.plot(x1,y2,'-',color='r')
ax2.legend((line1,line2),('line1','line2'),numpoints=1,loc='center')
l = line1[0]
l.remove()
l = line2[0]
l.remove()
ax2.set_axis_off()
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Now I just want to put the legend in the center for the ax2 subplot (in gap1) and remove *everything* (axis, lines, ticks etc.) *except* the legend which is in the center.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fig, axes_lst = plt.subplots(2, 1)

ln_1, ln_2 = axes_lst[0].plot(range(5), range(5), range(5), np.arange(5) ** 2)
axes_lst[1].legend((ln_1, ln_2), ('lin', 'quad'), loc='center')
plt.draw()
```

The handles used in the call to legend don't have to be on the `axes` that you calling `legend` on.

[image]

Comment: Adding axes_lst[1].set_axis_off() just before plt.draw() is what I wanted. Thanks @tcaswell.

Comment: I just dealt with the part you didn't have working ;).  If this solved you problem could you accept it?