# What does a 4-element tuple argument for 'bbox_to_anchor' mean in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the ["Legend location"](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location) section of the "Legend guide" in the matplotlib website, there's a small script where line 9 is `plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3, ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)`. All the tuples I've seen passed to `bbox_to_anchor` have 2 elements in it, but this one has 4. What does each element mean if the tuple passed has 4 elements? 

I was looking at it in the `pyplot.legend` [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend), and it said something about `bbox_transform` coordinates. So I looked around and found `matplotlib.transforms.Bbox` with a [`static from_bounds(x0, y0, width, height)`](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox). 

I was guessing the setup for the 4-tuple parameter was based on this `from_bounds`. I copied the script to Spyder, did `%matplotlib` in an Ipython console, and changed some values. It seemed to make sense, but when I tried only changing `.102` to something like `0.9`, the legend didn't change. I think the tuple is based on `from_bounds`, I just don't know why changing the last value in the tuple did nothing.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You're right, the 4-tuple in `plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3)` is set as `(x0, y0, width, height)` where `(x0,y0)` are the lower left corner coordinates of the bounding box.

While those parameters set the bounding box for the legend, the legend's actual vertical size is shrunk to the size that is needed to put the elements in. Further its position is determined only in conjunction with the `loc` parameter. The loc parameter sets the alignment of the legend inside the bounding box, such that for some cases, no difference will by seen when changing the `height`, compare e.g. plot (2) and (4).

[image]

Comment: What are the units of `width` and `height`? I can't help but think the use of `loc` and `bbox_to_anchor` is overly complicated, especially when their only purpose is to position the dang box somewhere on screen .. (apologies for the rant)

Comment: `width` and `height` are in the same coordinates as `x0` and `y0`. By default those are axes coordinates, but that may be changed using the `bbox_transform` argument. Note that the `loc` alone is enough to position the box anywhere on screen, but it is not sufficient to change the alignment together with the position.

Answer (score 44):

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer is excellent. I would like to expand about the meaning of `alignment` between the legend box and bounding box. It means that different position indicated by the parameter `loc` for both the legend box and bounding box will be put at the same point.

For example, if `loc='center'`, the center of legend box and the bounding box will be at the same point. If `loc='center right'`, the center right of legend box and the bounding box will be at the same point. Sorry for the verbosity...

Let's take a concrete example to illustrate this idea,

## Four coordinates for `bbox_to_anchor`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as patches

locs = ['upper right', 'lower left', 'center left', 'lower center', 'center',
        'right']

x0, y0, width, height = 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.4

x = np.arange(0.1, 4, 0.1)
y = 1.0/x

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

idx = 1
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, idx)
        ax.plot(x, y, label=r'$\frac{1}{x}$')
        ax.legend(loc=locs[idx-1], bbox_to_anchor=(x0, y0, width, height),
            edgecolor='g', fontsize='large', framealpha=0.5,
            borderaxespad=0)
        ax.add_patch(
            patches.Rectangle((x0, y0), width, height, color='r',
                            fill=False, transform=ax.transAxes)
        )
        ax.text(0.6, 0.2, s="loc = '{}'".format(locs[idx-1]),
        transform=ax.transAxes)
        idx += 1

plt.show()
```

The above code produces the image below,
[image]

In the image, the red box is the bounding box, and the green box is the legend box. `loc` in each subplot indicates the alignment relationship between the two boxes.

## Two coordinates for `bbox_to_anchor`

When there are only two values given to `bbox_to_anchor`, the bounding box width and height are set to zero. Let's modify the above code slightly,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as patches

locs = ['upper right', 'lower left', 'center left', 'lower center', 'center',
        'right']

x0, y0, width, height = 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0

x = np.arange(0.1, 4, 0.1)
y = 1.0/x

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

idx = 1
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, idx)
        ax.plot(x, y, label=r'$\frac{1}{x}$')
        ax.legend(loc=locs[idx-1], bbox_to_anchor=(x0, y0, width, height),
            edgecolor='g', fontsize='large', framealpha=0.5,
            borderaxespad=0)
        ax.add_patch(
            patches.Rectangle((x0, y0), width, height, color='r',
                            fill=False, transform=ax.transAxes)
        )
        ax.text(0.6, 0.2, s="loc = '{}'".format(locs[idx-1]),
        transform=ax.transAxes)
        ax.plot(x0, y0, 'r.', markersize=8, transform=ax.transAxes)
        idx += 1

plt.show()
```

Now, the produce image becomes

[image]

Red point in the above image indicates the bound box coordinate position.

Comment: Why, in your 'four coordinates' examples, does the "bounding box" not BOUND the legend?  What does it bound?  If nothing, what is meant by the term "bounding box"?