# Provide the absolute width of the space reserved for text in matplotlib legends

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is a MWE with a legend being produced:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( [1,2], [2,1], label='\$f_\mathrm{so}\$')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')
#fig.show()

rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'
fig.savefig('fig.svg', format='svg')
```

This is what the resulting `fig.svg` looks like:

[image: produced output]

Now I'm looking for a way to tell matplotlib to use less horizontal space for the legend text,
opting for a figure that looks like this:

[image: desired output]

I studied the [documentation of the legend API](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend) but didn't find a solution.
Is it actually not possible to influence the amount of space being used for the legend text?

**Background:**
I intend to include the `svg` file in a LaTeX documents via the `svg`-package such that the LaTeX commands are properly typeset. I would also have the ticklabels converted to something like `\btick{1.0}`, `\rtick{1.0}` etc.

### Update

There is a workaround [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41026480/7042795) answering the question [Fix size of legend in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026125/fix-size-of-legend-in-matplotlib).
The proposed remedy involves tailoring the `bbox_to_anchor` to the desired width of the legend, provided relative to the width of the axis.

In the context of the question [Fix size of legend in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026125/fix-size-of-legend-in-matplotlib) that is fine, but **I need a solution that enables me to set the absolute width of the legend**, such that it does not resize when changing the width of the axis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix size of legend in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026125/fix-size-of-legend-in-matplotlib)

Comment: It sort of does, indeed, but this approach (via bbox_to_anchor) requires me to specify the width of the bbox_to_anchor, and hence the width of the legend box relative to the width of the axis. This means that I have to adapt the call of ax.legend(...) whenever I change the width of the axis. That's quite fiddly. I would prefer a means of simply providing the absolute width of the legend box and  have the bbox_to_anchor untouched.