# Update legend text without updating size of legend box in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to update the text entries of matplotlib legends without having the size of the legend updated upon doing so.

Here is a MWE:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( [1,2], [2,1], label='$f_\mathrm{so}$')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')

rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'
fig.savefig('fig1.svg', format='svg')

texts = ax.get_legend().get_texts()
for text in texts:
  text.set_text( text.get_text().replace( r'\$', r'$' ).replace( r'$', r'\$' ) )

fig.savefig('fig2.svg', format='svg')
```

This is what the resulting files look like:

`fig1.svg`:
[image: fig1.svg]

`fig2.svg`:
[image: actual appearance of fig2.svg]

The legend box is well-sized in `fig1.svg` and I like to keep this size while only updating the legend text.
How could this be achieved?

Here is what I want `fig2.svg` to look like:
[image: desired appearance of fig2.svg]

### Update

JohanC pointed me to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026125/fix-size-of-legend-in-matplotlib) which gave me a few more clues on how to tackle this.

So, with `leg.get_window_extent()` I am able to get the current extent of the legend before updating the texts.
With `ax.legend( bbox_to_anchor=bbox, mode='expand', loc='lower left' )` I can then impose a new bbox to anchor to which I would make match the old size of the legend. The mode `expand` will have the labels run out of the legend box.
This can work because my legend texts always get longer but never shorter.

The only thing that I didn't figure out is how to convert the values in the variable `bbox` into those that I need to pass to `ax.legend`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot( [1,2], [2,1], label='$f_\mathrm{so}$')
ax.legend(loc='upper right')

rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'
fig.savefig('fig1.svg', format='svg')

# Get bbox prior to updating the text
leg = ax.get_legend()
bbox = leg.get_window_extent()
print(bbox) # prints Bbox(x0=501.72589246961803, y0=386.94444444444446, x1=569.0555555555555, y1=415.4555555555556)

# Freeze the size of the legend bbox
bbox=(0.8,0.8,0.2,0.2) # Values of variable bbox above should be used
ax.legend( bbox_to_anchor=bbox, mode='expand', loc='lower left' )

# update the texts
texts = ax.get_legend().get_texts()
for text in texts:
  text.set_text( text.get_text().replace( r'\$', r'$' ).replace( r'$', r'\$' ) )

fig.show()
fig.savefig('fig2.svg', format='svg')
```

produces
[image: fig2.svg new output]

Comment: Did you look into [Fix size of legend in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026125/fix-size-of-legend-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: Oh no I hadn't and this discussion provided some clues.
I feel like I am halfway there now.
I updated my question...