# How to specify legend position in graph coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am aware of the bbox_to_anchor keyword and this thread, which very helpfully suggests how to manually place the legend:

[How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)

However, I'd like to use the coordinates of my x- and y-axis in the graph to specify the legend position (inside the plot), as I might need to move the figure into a large figure with a different axis environment, and I don't want to manually play around with those coordinates every time I do this. Is this possible?

Edit: A small example is here:

```
import numpy as n
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
axarr[1].set_ylim([0.611,0.675])
axarr[0].set_ylim([0.792,0.856]) 
axarr[0].plot([0, 0.04, 0.08],n.array([ 0.83333333,  0.82250521,0.81109048]), label='test1') 
axarr[0].errorbar([0, 0.04, 0.08],n.array([ 0.8,  0.83,   0.82]),n.array([0.1,0.1,0.01]), label='test2') 
axarr[1].plot([0, 0.04, 0.08],n.array([ 0.66666667,  0.64888304,  0.63042428]))
axarr[1].errorbar([0, 0.04, 0.08],n.array([ 0.67,  0.64,  0.62]),n.array([ 0.01,  0.05,  0.1]))
axarr[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.04, 0.82, 1., .102),labelspacing=0.1,       handlelength=0.1, handletextpad=0.1,frameon=False, ncol=4, columnspacing=0.7)
```

[image]

I think what confuses me is that the legend does not actually start at 0.82, and indeed for my larger plot (with 5 subplots of this type), I need to use legend coordinates bbox_to_anchor=(0.04, 1.15, 1., .102) in order to make the legend appear on coordinates (0.02, 0.83). But maybe I am getting something else wrong?

Comment: Its not exactly clear in how far the solution from the linked question do not help you as by default the bbox_to_anchor argument takes the axes coordinates, just as you want it to be. You may want to give an example of what you are trying to achieve and/or better explain in how far the solutions are not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited it. But maybe you're right and I'm just misunderstanding something with how matplotlib places these legends in general - do you know which corner of the legend is placed on the coordinates that are given to bbox_to_anchor?

Comment: Well I thought I had a complete explanation into [my answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317). There is also the link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803385/what-does-a-4-element-tuple-argument-for-bbox-to-anchor-mean-in-matplotlib) included that shows how to interprete the 4-tuple bbox_to_anchor specification. I may still try to answer your question here, but for that I would need to know what exactly you mean when asking for "the legend appear on coordinates (0.02, 0.83)" is it the lower left corner that you want to have there?

Comment: Ouff sorry I thought I'd looked through the other post carefully, but I hadn't scrolled down far enough to see your answer - thank you, trying to understand this now. And yes, I did want to lower left corner to be at these coordinates.

Comment: Ok sorry, just to check if I get this right: so when I just say loc="upper right", and give no bbox_to_anchor specification, matplotlib interprets that as the loc with respect to the axes. But when I say loc="upper right" and give a bbox_to_anchor specification, that bbox_to_anchor specification will be interpreted with respect to the axes and the loc keyword refers to the corner of the legend?

Comment: Yes. In principle thats correct. Although there is really no difference. The default value of `bbox_to_anchor` is `(0,0,1,1)` and the `loc` always says in which corner of the bounding box the legend is placed. The result is the same as with your interpretation.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks so much, also for the detailed answer and the link to your other answer!!

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The `loc` parameter specifies in which corner of the bounding box the legend is placed. The default for `loc` is  `loc="best"` which gives unpredictable results when the `bbox_to_anchor` argument is used.
Therefore, when specifying `bbox_to_anchor`, **always** specify `loc` as well.

The default for `bbox_to_anchor` is `(0,0,1,1)`, which is a bounding box over the complete axes. If a different bounding box is specified, is is usually sufficient to use the first two values, which give (x0, y0) of the bounding box.

Below is an example where the bounding box is set to position `(0.6,0.5)` (green dot) and different `loc` parameters are tested. Because the legend extents outside the bounding box, the `loc` parameter may be interpreted as "which corner of the legend shall be placed at position given by the 2-tuple bbox_to_anchor argument".

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 6, 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
locs = ["upper left", "lower left", "center right"]
for l, ax in zip(locs, axes.flatten()):
    ax.set_title(l)
    ax.plot([1,2,3],[2,3,1], "b-", label="blue")
    ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,1], "r-", label="red")
    ax.legend(loc=l, bbox_to_anchor=(0.6,0.5))
    ax.scatter((0.6),(0.5), s=81, c="limegreen", transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

See especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317) for a detailed explanation and the question [What does a 4-element tuple argument for 'bbox_to_anchor' mean in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803385/what-does-a-4-element-tuple-argument-for-bbox-to-anchor-mean-in-matplotlib) .

---

If you want to specify the legend position in other coordinates than axes coordinates, you can do so by using the `bbox_transform` argument. If may make sense to use figure coordinates

```
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,0), loc="lower right",  bbox_transform=fig.transFigure)
```

It may not make too much sense to use data coordinates, but since you asked for it this would be done via `bbox_transform=ax.transData`.

Answer (score 34):

Way I use very often is *loc* argument in the legend function. String input works well:

```
plt.legend(loc = "upper left")
```

As documentation says, for the string referencing you can use:

```
        ===============   =============
        Location String   Location Code
        ===============   =============
        'best'            0
        'upper right'     1
        'upper left'      2
        'lower left'      3
        'lower right'     4
        'right'           5
        'center left'     6
        'center right'    7
        'lower center'    8
        'upper center'    9
        'center'          10
        ===============   =============
```

Comment: This does not answer the users question, these are not graph coordinates

Answer (score 24):

According to the [matplotlib legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html):

> The location can also be a 2-tuple giving the coordinates of the lower-left corner of the legend in axes coordinates (in which case *bbox_to_anchor* will be ignored).

Thus, one could use:

```
plt.legend(loc=(x, y))
```

to set the legend's lower left corner to the specified `(x, y)` position.

Note that the `x` and `y` coordinates here are relative, meaning that `x=0` is the left most point in the plot and `x=1` is the rightmost point in the plot. Similarly for `y=0` and `y=1` along the height of the plot, where `y=0` is the bottom, and `y=1` is the top.

Answer (score 10):

You can change location of legend using loc argument.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html?highlight=legend#matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plt.plot([3,2,1], label="test2")
# Place a legend above this subplot, expanding itself to
# fully use the given bounding box.
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
           ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)

plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plt.plot([3,2,1], label="test2")
# Place a legend to the right of this smaller subplot.
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry - how to the bbox_to_anchor and loc keywords interact? Will bbox_to_anchor place the legend at a position within the loc environment?

Comment: loc argument will inform matplotlib which part of the bounding box of the legend should be placed at the arguments of bbox_to_anchor.

Comment: @mzzx if you find this answer helpful (independent of whether you accept it or not) you may still upvote - which is kind of the same as saying "thanks".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's post, I use the following line to add a legend at an absolute position in a plot.

```
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0,1.0),\
    bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

For unknown reasons, `bbox_transform=fig.transFigure` does not work with me.

Comment: This is probably because you have more than one figure. To select the current figure you could use `plt.figure(fig.number)` and then use your `fig.transFigure` command, it should work.