# legend() duplicating itself

Tags: python, plot, legend

My following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import legend as legend

x = np.matrix(
    [
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]
    ]
)

y = x.transpose()

xx = x
yy = y+0.2

# Vertical Lines of grid:

plt.plot(x, y, 'b-o', label='data1')
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'r-*', label='data2')
legend()
plt.show()
```

generates figures looking like

[image]

I'd like to do two things:

1. stop the legend from duplicating it self; it should only show each label once; something like

[image]

2. position the legend nicely; say put it upper right corner with no overlap with the content of the graph

Easy/elegant solution is really appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The legend placement is quite well documented:  https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `x` (and therefore, all your other arrays) is a 2-d array, when you call `plot()` on it, it is equivalent to calling `plot()` on several 1-d sets, so you're creating a label for each one of these plots.

One way to circumvent this is to assign the plots to a variable, and then insert a legend only for the first one of each.

```
lines = plt.plot(x, y, 'b-o')
other_lines = plt.plot(xx, yy, 'r-*')
plt.legend([lines[0], other_lines[0]], ['data1', 'data2'])
```

For legend positioning, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413020/how-to-specify-legend-position-in-matplotlib-in-graph-coordinates) or at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/legend_guide.html).

Comment: Thanks     a                   lot   !, I will also look into the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `x` and `y` are matrices, each matrix row gets the same label which is duplicated in the legend.

The solution might look like this:

```
for i in range(x.size[0]):
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i], label='data1' if i == 0 else None)
    plt.plot(xx[i], yy[i], label='data2' if i == 0 else None)
```

Comment: Sorry, I know I can do this, but this is not what I preferred. I'd hope there are some other solutions?