# Place legend above the ax at a consistent distance

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to place a legend just above the ax in matplotlib using ax.legend(loc=(0, 1.1)); however, if I change the figure size from (5,5) to (5,10) the legend shows up at a different distance from the top edge of the plot.

Is there any way to reference the top edge of the plot and offset it a set distance from it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a constant distance between the legend bounding box and the axes by default. This is set via the `borderaxespad` parameter. This defaults to the rc value of `rcParams["legend.borderaxespad"]`, which is usually set to `0.5` (in units of the fontsize).

So essentially you get the behaviour you're asking for for free. Mind however that you should specify the `loc` to the corner of the legend from which that padding is to be taken. I.e.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for figsize in [(5,4), (5,9)]:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    ax.plot([1,2,3], label="label")

    ax.legend(loc="lower left", bbox_to_anchor=(0,1))

plt.show()
```

[image]

For more detailed explanations on how to position legend outside the axes, see [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317). Also relevant: [How to specify legend position in matplotlib in graph coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413020/how-to-specify-legend-position-in-matplotlib-in-graph-coordinates/44414858#44414858)