# How to move legend to outside of a seaborn scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, scatter-plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

g = sns.scatterplot(x="Area", y="Rent/Sqft", hue="region", style="availability", data=df)
```

When I run this I get the below plot.

[image]

I want to move the legend outside of plot. I googled and tried the following

```
g.legend(loc='right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.5), ncol=1)
plt.show()
```

But I don't get any output. Moreover, I can't understand how the object plt is connected to my sns object

I am using Jupyter Notebook, Python 3.6 and Seaborn 0.9.0.

Comment: Maybe you would rather use `ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 0.5), ncol=1)`, but appart it works fine for me. Can you explain in more detail what "But I don't get any output." means?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Please try the following:

`g.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.5), ncol=1)`

You can change the first number to negative to put your legend on the left side if you want.

If you're using Jupyter IDE, you need to put both lines of your code in the same cell and run them together to get the output. In addition, there is no such thing as `sns` object. Most of the functions in [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) return a matplotlib `Axes` object where you can use all the methods associated with the `Axes` object, like the one (i.e., `.legend()`) you are using here.

Comment: If you don't specify `loc`, it will be `"best"`, making the position unpredictable. In turn this means you should **always** use `loc` for non-automatic placements. Did you read my comment below the question?

Comment: 'best' is the default setting indeed, but I think it is unpredictable when you don't pass anything in `bbox_to_anchor`.

Comment: It is always unpredictable, independent on whether you use the default axes bbox or supply your custom box.

Comment: Is there any reference? I'm interested in it.

Comment: The [legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) states that `loc="best"` is default. What "best" is, would depend on the data in the axes, but if the legend is outside of the axes, it can become anything; meaning in this case the lower left corner could be at `(1.25, 0.5)` but if you're unlucky, its the upper right corner that is at that position. Hence, one should specify `loc` to be sure it is the corner of desire. I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317) is a useful read.

Comment: Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803385/what-does-a-4-element-tuple-argument-for-bbox-to-anchor-mean-in-matplotlib) provides more details.