# matplotlib: align figure legend with suptitle (bottom of text, vertically aligned)

Tags: matplotlib, alignment, anchor, legend, title

I have a subplot with an external, horizontal legend (figure legend), and super title (`suptitle`). I would like to align them on the bottom of the text, vertically. I set the vertical position of the title with `fig.suptitle('title', ha='left', y=placement)`. When I try to set the legend's location with `fig.legend(handles, labels, loc=(0.65, placement))`, It is not aligned. I suspect this is an issue with the point the objects are aligned on and that the legend has a border... so I changed the padding of the legend to 0, but still have to tweak it.

How could I explicitly set the anchor point, or node, of the suptitle and legend?

**EDIT**

Image attached below. I believe I have solved the problem with setting the `suptitle` parameter `va='bottom`, and `legend` parameters `borderpad=0.0, borderaxespad=0`. Now, if I do have a border, how would I do this? I would also like to know how to explicitly set the anchor point of the legend.

**SOLUTION**

When you set the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter in the legend, it basically changed where the legend is clipped to. If the `bbox` has no height or width (2-tuple), it is a point. The `loc` parameter is then the point on the legend frame that is anchored to the `bbox`. When `loc` is used on it's on, the `bbox` is determined by MPL.

Let's say I wanted the title on the left, legend on the right (with no box), and horizontally aligned at the bottom. Mmy solution would look like:

```py
fig.suptitle('title', ha='left', va='bottom', y=placement, x=0.02)
fig.legend(handles, labels, 
    loc='lower right',
    bbox_to_anchor=(0.98, placement), 
    borderpad=0.0,
    borderaxespad=0,
    ncol=3,
)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add an image of how the plot currently looks like and how you want it to look? Also, please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You will definitely need to use `verticalalignment="bottom"` for the suptitle. Also, how did you change the padding? Using `borderpad=0, borderaxespad=0` it should be perfectly aligned (but will of course look awful).

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I thought `va=baseline` would work at first.. but tried `va='bottom` on your suggestion and it has improved-I think it is perfectly aligned now. Please note that I have no border on the legend. If I did however, this presents another problem. I'm assuming vertical/horizontal alginment changes the anchor?

Comment: @FranciscaConcha-Ramírez please see the updated question.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803385/what-does-a-4-element-tuple-argument-for-bbox-to-anchor-mean-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for.