# Legend in matplotlib jumps around with minimal change to bbox_to_anchor parameters

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have this issue in matplotlib that drives me crazy. I want to position the legend within the plot to be in a certain position, for example, in this case, in the top left corner (matching the corner of the plot). I do not want to use the `loc` parameter as it doesn't give me the exact location I want. To achieve what I want, I use `bbox_to_anchor`. The issue is that with a minimal change to the `x,y` parameter, the legend jumps all over the place. Why is it happening? What's going on? How can I fix it?

For instance with `bbox_to_anchor=(0.12,.9)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), label='Sine')
ax.plot(x, np.arctan(x), label='Inverse tan')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.12,.9))

plt.show()
```

[image]

and with `bbox_to_anchor=(0.13,.9)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), label='Sine')
ax.plot(x, np.arctan(x), label='Inverse tan')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.13,.9))

plt.show()
```

[image]

And finally with `bbox_to_anchor=(0.13,.8)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), label='Sine')
ax.plot(x, np.arctan(x), label='Inverse tan')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.13,.8))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You still need to use loc with some value, otherwise it defaults to auto and jumps around relative to the bbox.

Comment: @JodyKlymak hmm, so you're suggesting that there is an interaction between the `loc` and the `bbox`? I thought that the loc is by default `best` but is set, from that place you can move it around using the bbox. But why would the loc change if you change bbox? It doesn't make sense, I don't understand..

Comment: When `bbox_to_anchor` is used, `loc` sets the anchor point. See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html): bbox_to_anchor: *Box that is used to position the legend in conjunction with loc*

Comment: See also [bbox_to_anchor and loc in matplotlib[](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068384/bbox-to-anchor-and-loc-in-matplotlib)

Comment: What both of you, @JohanC and JodyKlymak, suggest is that `loc` sets the anchor point and `bbox_to_anchor` is then relative to this anchor point. But in the post, the `loc` is the same it is the default. So the anchor point should be the same. So what is the legend dancing around? I still don't understand

Comment: With `loc='best'` (the default), matplotlib tries the 9 possible `loc` positions and chooses the one with the least overlap.  If you also give a `bbox_to_anchor`, the optimal position will be calculated taken that position into account. Therefore, the legend will jump around somewhat.  It is recommended to explicitly set a `loc`.

Comment: If you don't specify it, `bbox_to_anchor` is the bbox of the parent axes.  If you specify the full `bbox_to_anchor` as a `(x0, y0, dx, dy)` four-tuple, the legend is placed in that bbox, but this the same algorithm as the full axes bbox.  If you just specify a two-tuple, `(x0, y0)`, the legend will touch this point, but if you don't specify *loc* it will still try to choose the "best" loc, and hence will spin around `(x0, y0)` depending on what is in your figure.  See also https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/legend_guide.html#legend-location

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto comments by others with my interpretation of the [source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.8.2/lib/matplotlib/legend.py) for matplotlib legend: `bbox_to_anchor` is set first, followed by `set_loc` for the legend. So if you don't specify `loc` then a default value will be used and apply your `bbox_to_anchor` values to the legend (can't trace down which default is used). Think of this as temporarily drawing your legend onto the figure. Then later the `loc` will be updated since by default `best` is used, which waits until the figure is drawn to compute the best location. With your legend already temporarily drawn on  your figure, the computation of the "best" location may return a new `loc` value than the default. Then your `bbox_to_anchor` values are again applied to the legend using the new `loc`.

In short, if you want predictable behavior, just set `loc`